# Decoding x265 HEVC more efficiently

Tags: video, graphics-card, video-conversion, video-streaming, codec

I have an old Extreme i7 first generation with 12 threads running a PLEX server. LAtely I've started adding more files compiled using x265 over x264. I noticed that when the system runs a x265 file, the CPU will spike to 100% generally. This does not happen with x264 files and I am not entirely sure. Aren't the 2 basically the same?

Anyway, my main question is this:
Is it possible to in some way offload decoding to a GPU of some sort to reduce the CPU stress?

Comment: What makes you think two different compression algorithms are 'basically' the same?

Comment: Isn't 265 basically open sourced version of 264? At least what I read somewhere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding

Answer (score 1):

Since january 2015 intel has included igpu hardware acceleration (haswell, skylake,etc). In addition, most modern graphics cards have a HW decoder for 8bit H.265 codecs (LAV filters supported it in 2014). Lastly, PowderDVD apparently offers (via OpenCL) hybrid acceleration of 10bit HEVC for the AMD R9 fury GPUs.

I don't know how PLEX decodes HEVC, but I think it should not spike even without GPU acceleration.